# Component over ng-container

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

Im trying to apply vertical nav component (from clarity) inside a custom component (for rehusability). The basic format of clarity vertical nav is:

```
<div class="content-container">
    <clr-vertical-nav>
      ... nav content ...
    </clr-vertical-nav>
    <div class="content-area">
         ... site content ...
    </div>
</div>
```

My sidenav component ('[layout-sidenav]') call only vertical's nav :

**layout/sidenav.html**

```
 <clr-vertical-nav> .... </clr-vertical-nav>
```

And i can apply it from my main component and works:

**layout.component.html**

```
<div class="content-container">
    <div layout-sidenav [items]="items"></div>
    <div class="content-area">
        ...site content...
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is, when i apply component over `div`, it broke clarity sidenav css, and i need act like `ng-container`, but when i apply it:

```
<div class="content-container">
    <ng-container layout-sidenav [items]="items"></ng-container>
    <div class="content-area">
        ...site content...
    </div>
</div>
```

I got an error.

```
LayoutComponent.html:23 ERROR TypeError: el.setAttribute is not a function
at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.setAttribute (platform-browser.js:1317)
at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.applyToHost (platform-browser.js:1385)
at DomRendererFactory2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DomRendererFactory2.createRenderer (platform-browser.js:1242)
at AnimationRendererFactory.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js.AnimationRendererFactory.createRenderer (animations.js:127)
at DebugRendererFactory2.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugRendererFactory2.createRenderer (core.js:12225)
at createComponentView (core.js:11179)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:12204)
at Object.debugCreateComponentView [as createComponentView] (core.js:11715)
at createViewNodes (core.js:11220)
at createEmbeddedView (core.js:11163)
```

Comment: What is the error are you getting? Can you share your code as well? The provided code snippet are not so informative :)

Comment: Share the error

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: have you tried ng-template?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout-sidenav has a template, so it clearly is a component, not a directive. The cases for a component to have an **attribute selector** rather than an element selector are very rare, and it really seems that in your case your selector should be `layout-sidenav`, not `[layout-sidenav]`.

Now, looking at the error you have, it seems you are adding an attribute to the host of the layout-sidenav component. `<ng-container>` is **not an HTML element**, so you cannot add attributes, classes or event listeners to it.

Long story short, you should definitely use an element selector for your component and use it as:

```
<layout-sidenav [items]="items"></layout-sidenav>
```

Comment: the author wanted to draw content of the `layout-sidenav` without `<layout-sidenav>` in the resulting html as it breaks sidenav css